# Why is the IF condition is being ignored - Shell

Tags: shell

I have an `if` statement like below.

```
if [ $? -eq 0 ]
echo "err A is $?"
then
alrtid="OK"
echo "DO THIS"
else
echo "Do THAT"
alrtid="NOK"
```

But when I execute this it returns:

```
'[' 1 -eq 0 ']'
echo 'err A is 1'
err A is 1
alrtid=OK
```

As per the statement, it should return the alert 'NOK'. Why does this behaviour occur?

Comment: 'then' goes right after ( or below in new line), 'if', you have it after the 'echo'

Comment: @bistoco The syntax is legal, even if it doesn't provide the result you *expect*.

Comment: @chepner: You say it's legal; could you explain, why? I looked up the *dash* manual (which, AFIK, implements the POSIX standard), and it explicitly says that the `then` must follow the `if`. It doesn't say what should happen if there are statements in between, so from this, I would conclude that it is syntactically illegal, but the shell decided to not output an error message, but instead simply exhibits undefined behaviour.

Comment: The condition of an `if` statement just has to be a *list*, which is any sequence of commands separated by `;`, `&`, newlines, `&&`, or `||`. That's why the `if` statement has a special keyword `then` to terminate the condition. (The [Posix spec](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_09_03) is a little clearer about this than the `dash` man page.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `echo`, being the last command of the condition, is what `if` tests to determine which branch to take. Try this instead:

```
if rv=$?; echo "err A is $rv"; [ "$rv" -eq 0 ]; then
```

Note that in your original, the value of `$?` in your `echo` command is the result of the `[` that immediately precedes it, not the value that `[` tests.

Comment: You are the best Chepner.

Comment: Note that, stylistically, most people would simply write `rv=$?; echo "err A is $rv"; if ...`.

Comment: Yeah, I'm not sure I've ever been tempted to do anything like this in an `if` condition. (Loop conditions, yes, but not `if`s.)